# Split the US into east and west via longitude filter

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to filter my dashboard using a U.S. East or U.S. West Radio Button/Checkbox. I have tried using longitude as the filter but the only option is a sliding scale. Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a separate calculated field in Tableau which defines your east vs. west longitude cutoff.  Something like:

```
If longitude > 105 
THEN "West"
ELSE "East"
END
```

Then use that field as filter on your view, customizing the filter option such that it is a radio button, and at least one must be chosen at any time.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you.